# Activity Spinner in Xamarin doesn't instantly update

Tags: xamarin, binding

So I have this problem...
I have an activity Indicator in Xamarin set up like this

```
<ActivityIndicator  IsRunning="{Binding IsSearching}" />
```

In my page class I bind it up like this...

```
private BindableProperty IsSearchingProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("IsSearching", typeof(bool), typeof(MainPage), false);

    public bool IsSearching
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsSearchingProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(IsSearchingProperty, value) ;
        }
    }
```

Everythig works but only one problem. The spinner won't initialize before the method from which it is called is not finished... For example...

```
private async void New_Survey_Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IsSearching = true;
        some method that takes a long time...

        await Navigation.PushAsync(new SurveyNavigationPage());
    }
```

In this case the IsSearching true value will get initialized after the compiler hits await. Truly stuck with this issue. Please help. Thank you.

UPDATE 1___________________________
So after some debugging here is what exactly is going on.

1) IsSearching is hit which takes the program to the setter.
2) After it hits the setter it continues to the method that takes a long time.
3) Only after it is done with the time consuming method and goes out of the New_Survey_Button_OnClicked it actually hits the getter and updates the UI.

Comment: "some method that takes a long time..." is blocking your UI thread

Comment: Maybe I should invoke it on a different thread and see what happens...

Comment: Yes.  Long running tasks shouldn't execute on the main thread

Comment: The only problem is that it is actually an async method that I am waitng for. I made it synchronous with .Result because I need to wait for it to get the info before I proceed to the next page. Guess that is a wrong apprach probably should make this run async and go for an event driven approach and simply move on to the next page when the asyn method is done. Maybe this approach will work better.